# Spring boot aws deployment issue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat

I deployed a spring boot war file to tomcat locally without any issue. It is running successfully. But while deploying same war to aws after running i am getting this log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at com.socialhub.crichub.Application.main(Application.java:28) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) ~[CrichubsWeb-1.0.0.war:1.0.0]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:279) ~[validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$Jsr303ValidatorFactory.run(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:401) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.getJavaRelease(Version.java:36) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar!/:5.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar!/:5.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar!/:5.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:31) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar!/:5.2.2.Final]
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276) ~[validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/:na]
        ... 27 common frames omitted

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
        at com.socialhub.crichub.Application.main(Application.java:28)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:279)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$Jsr303ValidatorFactory.run(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:401)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.getJavaRelease(Version.java:36)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:31)
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
        ... 27 more
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>palebluedotstardust</groupId>
    <artifactId>dfsdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>fdsf</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


        <org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>
        <javax.servlet-api.version>2.5</javax.servlet-api.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--<commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version> -->


    </properties>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>


    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


    <repositories>


        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- ###################### Spring boot ################### -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ###################### Spring Security ################### -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <!-- ###################### Spring boot ################### -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.8.0.M1</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.5</version> -->
        </dependency>


        <!-- ###################### MongoDB ################### -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.0.2</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- ###################### MongoDB ################### -->
        <!-- ###################### Jersey 2.0 ################### -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ###################### Jersey 2.0 ################### -->
        <!-- ###################### Validation ################### -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.2.2.Final</version> -->

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ###################### Validation ################### -->
        <!-- ###################### Mail ################### -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ###################### Mail ################### -->
        <!-- ###################### Logging ################### -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ###################### Logging ################### -->
        <!-- ###################### File copy, Directory move operation ################### -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ###################### GeoLiteCity ################### -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoip-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>4.2.0.RC1</version> -->
        </dependency>


        <!-- ###################### GeoLiteCity ################### -->

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

any clue?

Comment: please share your `pom.xml`

Comment: added the pom.xml. please check

Comment: not sure but it all started with **org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.getJavaRelease(Version.java:36)** , just curious what java version are you using

Comment: @ShaileshChandra java 8

Comment: please follow my  answer.

Comment: suggested a pom change, let me know if that works

Answer (score 3):

can you change

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

to below, It appears to me, a version mismatch of the jar version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>

</dependency>
```

**in fact with spring boot, you need not provide a version for most of the dependency as it comes from spring boot dependency management**

Answer (score 2):

I have the same probleme and when I add this it's ok

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look up for following issues:

1. There should be no dependency with scope provided.For example I see

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

have scope provided. Please remove this scope.

2. There are no IAM permissions issue to allow download of the dependencies.

Also, I would suggest that you use docker container image to avoid such issues i.e. what image you build on local is getting promoted to higher environment.